# JGitInternalException while adding files

Tags: java, git, jgit

I just tried to start working with JGit and am now stuck with a strange exception, while doing most basic things.

My code:

```
public class JGitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File worktree = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\nils\\Desktop\\tmp\\gittest\\jgittest");
        File repodir = new File(worktree, ".git");

        Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(repodir);

        Git git = new Git(repository);
        git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception, when executing this snippet:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of add command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:212)
    at de.njo.test.JGitTest.main(JGitTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.newTempFile(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.toTemp(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.insert(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryInserter.insert(ObjectDirectoryInserter.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:188)
    ... 1 more
```

I get a very similar exception, when running this snippet on a Java EE-server. Where is my mistake?

EDIT: Further informations:

- the created repository is completely empty (no directories: hooks, HEAD or
  anything at all)
- I'm using JGit v3.7.0.201502260915-r

Comment: Do you intend to create a repository (i.e. `git init`) in `C:\Users\nils\Desktop\tmp\gittest\jgittest` or does the directory already contain a repository? Despite its name, `FileRepositoryBuilder.create()` does not create a repository. To initialize a repository, use `Git.init().setDirectory( "c:\users\..." ).call()`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do a "git init" ... I will try your proposal.

Comment: It does work, but leaves me very puzzled... According to this site: https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit, FileRepositoryBuilder.create(repodir) is the way to go for a new repository...

Comment: Also sounds that way here: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/CreateNewRepository.java

Comment: The instructions in the first link are sinply wrong. The jgit-cookbook snippet uses `repository.create();` on the repository returned by `FileRepositoryBuilder.create()` which actually initializes the repository.The `FileRepositoryBuilder` is *only* used to create instances of `Repository` for existing git repositories. Read [more on this here](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/). While the cookbook approach may work, the designated way to initialize a repository with JGit is through the `InitCommand` as sugested above.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'd be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the `JGitInternalException` is that there is no repository at the specified location.

Despite its name, `FileRepositoryBuilder.create()` does not create (i.e. `git init`) a repository. The `FileRepositoryBuilder` can only be used to create instances of `Repository` (the class that represents a repository in JGit) for existing git repositories. Read [more on this here](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/).

To initialize a new repository, use

```
Git git = Git.init().setDirectory( "c:\users\..." ).call();
```

And don't forget to `git.close()` the repository once you are done using it.